# Access static field in polymer expression

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

It is possible to access static fields in dart polymer expression?

In my template I need to access some static value from a know class, how can I access it in polymer expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to access it directly. I think you need to create a getter to the Polymer element where you want to use the value.

You can also create a mixin that provides access to the static values.

Another solution is to create a component that provides access to the static values and use it like

```dart
<polymer-element name="xx-yy">
  <template>
    <my-const id="my-const"></my-const>
    <template if="{{$['my-const'].isDebug}}">
      some debug output
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: This is the solution that I'm using now, but it becomes annoying if you have a large set of constants.

Comment: You could create a mixin with the getters and just add this to your Polymer element class.

Comment: Nice suggestion. In the meantime I've opened an enhancement request: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21592